# How to place a PageControl in ScrollView having multiple images?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, xcode6, uipagecontrol

I have a scroll view which contain a view and view have five images in want a pagecontrol to show the navigation status but the page control hides behind the images. I tried everything searched internet but cant fined anything.

Implementation.h

```
@interface ScrollSecondViewController : UIViewController
{
   IBOutlet UIView *scrContentSizeView;
   IBOutlet UIScrollView * scrollView;

}
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIPageControl *pageControl;
@end
```

Implementation.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
[self.navigationItem setTitle:@"Scroll View"];
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrContentSizeView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height);  
scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;

     [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(750, 0) animated:YES];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
```

}

```
- (void) scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    _pageControl.currentPage = scrollView.contentOffset.x /       scrollView.frame.size.width;
}
```

Comment: Are you changing the frame/constraints of your page control somewhere ? Did you set the numberOfPages for your control ? (make sure is not 0). What's the frame of your control ?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/a/triffort.com/file/d/0B__F6yL7OYWCUmJOcGZYOGZhbXM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/a/triffort.com/file/d/0B__F6yL7OYWCemxhVGlOYWs1bXM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: here is the screenshot of what i am trying to do...hope this will clear you what is going on

Comment: @danypata        is it enough ?????

Comment: Can you add the screenshot in your question and what is the content size of scrollView?

Comment: I can't see the `numberOfPages` for your page control, the screenshots are kind of useless... Please try to add some screenshots to this questions with your page control configs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the viewDidLoad method you should add the following code as the last method you call after adding all subviews.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad]; 

   //do what u want

  //this should be last
 [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.pageControl];  
}
```